# Extracting TLD using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing

I have an array of domain names formatted like this:

```
www.example.com
www.example.co.uk
```

from which I would like to extract the top-level TLDs, which would result in (respectively):

```
com
uk
```

To do this in PHP, I am using the regex:

```
preg_match("`(?<=\.)\w+$`", $cc, $tld_array);
```

This is meant to match the last `.` in a domain up to the end of the string. I expected this to give me

```
com
uk
```

as above, but instead only received

```
NULL
uk
```

Can anyone see why second-level TLDs are working while first-level TLDs don't?

RegExr suggests they should as well: http://regexr.com?31gsg

Comment: Are you retrieving the string from $tld_array[0]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting here since a comment won't work for this:

```
php > $cc = 'www.example.com';
php > preg_match("`(?<=\.)\w+$`", $cc, $tld_array);
php > print_r($tld_array);
Array
(
    [0] => com
)
```

if this doesn't work for you, make sure that your example.com string doesn't have some non-printable chars hiding in it.

Comment: I am running my query again with some debugging to peer into what's going on.

Comment: You were right, there were unexpected characters in the input.

Comment: this is not working for com.de or tld that has two domain names.

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to use regular expressions for everything :-) A nice alternative:

```
echo substr($domain, strrpos($domain, ".")+1);
```

Comment: Surely that only finds the first ., so for example for www.example.co.uk it will return example.co.uk?

Comment: No, that would be if I used strpos instead of strrpos. The latter function searches from end to start, so my answer works.

Comment: Neat! Thanks. I would mark your answer as correct but techically the answer by Marc B is the most direct answer to my question so it'll have to go to him.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat :-)

Comment: Thanks mate - i actully did use strpos instead of strrpost to grab the sld & tld... i dont see any issuse with that - think i might face one with any type of domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you need extract only "uk" from "www.example.co.uk", solution with string functions is pretty good. But, it isn't correct way for extracting real TLD, for example, TLD for "www.example.co.uk" is "co.uk", not "uk".

You need package that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.). I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Here example of code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('www.example.co.uk');
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'co.uk'
```

Comment: Indeed, a package the way for this. I went for [Utopia Domains](https://github.com/utopia-php/domains)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without regex, I suggest using php's parse_url function at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Example (you can also find this on php.net):

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```